# JSONP issue querying a REST service

Tags: jquery, rest, jsonp

I am having problems using JQuery's JSONP:

http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/tuCvT/

```
$.ajax({
    url           : url,
    dataType      : 'jsonp',
    contentType   : "application/json",
    jsonpCallback : 'cback',
    crossDomain   : true,
    jsonp         : false,
    success       : function(json) {console.log("RESP: " + json)}, 
    error         : function(error) {console.log("ERROR: " + error.message)}
});
```

Debugging with Chrome's developer tools I can see that the REST server is passing the data back, but the "error" callback is always called.
I have tried several combinations of options without luck.

Any ideas?

SOLVED: I was using a wrong url that was asking for a json (not jsonp) response. Fixed version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/tuCvT/1/

Comment: what's the status code of the response? it will not trigger error based on response but based on the status code.

Comment: @HungryCoder, The status code is 200 OK.

Comment: @emepyc Go ahead and provide your "SOLVED" info as an answer to your own question and accept it as the correct answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I was using a wrong url that was asking for a json (not jsonp) response. Fixed version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/tuCvT/1/

```
var url = prefix + species + "/" + chr + ":" + fromPos + "-" + toPos + ".jsonp?feature=gene;callback=" + cback;
```